# Staple a git repository on top of another?

Tags: git

I had a project I was working on and let's pretend it had commits a1,a2,a3,a4 and a5.

I decided to restart the project from scratch and created a new repository. It has commits b1,b2,b3,b4,b5.

But I ultimately decided that the history from a1-a5 are relevant to b1-b5, so I would like the history to be as such:

- a1 -> 1
- a2 -> 2
- a3 -> 3
- a4 -> 4
- a5 -> 5
- b1 -> 6
- b2 -> 7
- b3 -> 8
- b4 -> 9
- b5 -> 10

So my thought to approach this is to

1. start in project a
2. add project b as a remote branch

Now my first attempt was to `git merge --allow-unrelated-histories b/master` but this changes the `master` branch to only have history of `1,2,3,4,5,10`.

How can I place all five commits from repository b's master on top of repository a's master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. start in project a
2. add project b as a remote branch

That's correct. The final step is to rebase b on top of a. Assuming a has master, and b was added as remote b...

```
git checkout b/master
git rebase master
```

You might get a lot of conflicts depending on how a and b were edited.

---

> *Now is there any way to retroactively add an old commit to A which rm -rf the entire repository (besides .git) so that the old files don't seep into the new files?*

If you're just going to delete everything in A, that tells me it's for historical/archeological purposes only. In that case there's little point in plopping B on top of A. Instead, make A an archival branch.

In B...

```
* git remote add a path/to/a
* git fetch a
* git branch a a/master
* git remote rm a
```

Now your repository has a as a branch for later inspection.

Comment: Thanks! Now is there any way to retroactively add an old commit to A which `rm -rf` the entire repository (besides .git) so that the old files don't seep into the new files?

Comment: @lanza Yes, you could `git rm` all the files in a final commit on A before rebasing B. At that point I'd question why you're merging the histories if they have no relation. If A is a dead project, leave it as a branch. PS I had the rebase backwards.

Comment: There are a ton of connections between the two, but it was drag/drop and copy/paste between the two since I didn't have a clue how to do that in git back then. But the two projects are definitively one project where I just got overwhelmed with trying to figure out git and decided to drag/drop from scratch.

Comment: @lanza There's still little point to dumping one branch on top of the other. If you're going to delete A, it's just for historical purposes. Leave it as a branch of B.

Comment: Fair enough, I just added an `archive` branch. Thanks!